# Ask user to choose from array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm practicing Java and wanted to let the user choose an option from the Array such as:

```
String Food[] = {"Beans","Rice","Spaghetti"};
```

So far I only know of Scanner, but this is my first program so I don't know much of the subject.

Also, is there a way to print it? besides doing:

```
System.out.println(Food[0]); //and so on
```

for every single one of them.

Edit: not a Array list.

Comment: Sidenote: That is an array and not an ArrayList.

Comment: btw you need to override toString in the Food....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the `Array` not `ArrayList` by doing:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Food));
```

It will print out: `[Beans, Rice, Spaghetti]`

If you are talking about an `ArrayList`, you would have to do:

```
ArrayList<String> Food = new ArrayList<String>();

Food.add("Beans");
Food.add("Rice");
Food.add("Spaghetti");
```

Then, you can loop over the `ArrayList` and build your own `String` with a `StringBuilder`

After reading your comment, I think you have a problem structuring your program. I will help you with that. Basically you have to complete these steps:

1. Program starts
2. Program outputs the options available in the menu
3. Program asks the user to choose one of the listed options
4. User chooses an option
5. Program will repeat step 3, only if the user wants to keep adding stuff to his order.
6. If the user does not want anything else, the Program outputs the total cost of the order

Some ideas of how to achieve this the right way:

1. I would use a `class` to encapsulate the characteristics of an "order". For instance: description, name, and price are important stuff that you need to be able to track per item.
2. when you don't know how many times your program will run, you have two options: using a `do while` loop or a `while` loop. Try to think in a condition that could make your program run indefinitely a number of times until the user is done. Inside the loop, you could have a `sum` variable where you would keep track of the items that the user wants.
3. It is better to keep track of items by just using numbers than `Strings`. Computers are faster to find stuff this way. So, if you use a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to mock a database system in your program, it would make it better and faster. Then, instead of using `if else` to control your flow, you could use a `switch` instead.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, it helped me out with the Printing problem, still have to wait for someone to enlighten me about user input.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? the `Scanner` is the way to ask for input in a console program.

Comment: Trying to ask the user for input, let's say, when the user chooses one of the options, it will run `if else` to set the price, later on, it will calculate the price of all the items chosen and delivery cost depending on it, at least that's what I am aiming for atm.

Comment: I think I understand what you need. Check out my edit @LucasMatheus

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: For a more efficient way of printing out the contents of the array, use an enhanced for-loop:

```
for(String f : Food)
{
    System.out.println(f);
}
```

This is effectively the same as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Food.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(Food[i])
}
```

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do correctly, I think this should suffice (disclaimer, it's been a while since I've worked with `Scanner()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] food = {"Beans","Rice","Spaghetti"}; // Java standards are lowercase for variables and objects, uppercase for class names.
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What would you like to eat? Options:");
    for(String f : food)
    {
        System.out.println(f);
    }
    String response = in.next();

    boolean validEntry = false;
    for(String f: food)
    {
        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase(f))
        {
            validEntry = true;
        }
    }

    if(validEntry)
    {
        System.out.println("You chose " + response);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please retry.")
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(String f : Food[])` would not be correct. Remove brackets.